# Can the name under the Bank Account be different from Account holder?

Tags: app-store-connect, developer-program

My sister made an iTunes Connect account and signed up for the developer program (she is over 21). I am the developer of the account; i'm just not exactly 18 yet (will be in a couple months).

In setting up the agreements/tax/banking, can she input my bank account information, since it has a different name than that on the developer account? If not, is there anything she can do (add me as a developer or something) to be able to?

Answer (score 1):

Per the [iTunes Connect Developer Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ManagingContractsandBanking.html) (emphasis mine):

> Specify the bank account.
>
> Identify the bank account by the following:
>
> ...
>
> Account Holder Name. Be sure that the Account Holder Name exactly matches the name **expected by the bank**; it **doesn't have to match the Legal Entity Name** for the iTunes Connect organization.

Comment: Can the bank account holder be younger than 18 years of age?

Comment: You would need to ask Apple. It is not mentioned in the Developer Guide.