# iTunes Connect - Use different bank account in the Agreement, Tax and Banking

Tags: ios, itunes, ios-appstore, app-store-connect, apple-store

I wanted to buy an Apple developer account, I live in Pakistan and my country is not in Apple supported countries.

I asked my friend who lives in the United kingdom to buy an account for me and thanks to him he did. Now, I have an account, but I need to setup Baking and Tax information in iTunes connect. That is where I need your guidance! Can you help with these questions?

- Can I set up my bank account instead of my friend (whose credit card
  was used to buy account and the account is in his name) to receive
  money in? (My Pakistani bank is available in supporting banks)
- Do I need to fill US tax form? If yes, then which options I should
  select?    I find it very confusing. (I want to sell my apps at all
  Over the    World)

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the bank account, see [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/151337/can-the-name-under-the-bank-account-be-different-from-account-holder/151649#151649). You would need to consult Apple as to whether the US tax documents are necessary.